# JSON - proper way to decode string in JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, dojo, json

I'm wondering what would be the best way to decode JSON string inside Javascript code.

I want my json string to be embeded inside my JS, like this:

```
var params = dojo.fromJson('<?=json_encode($this->params); ?>');
```

dojo.fromJson decodes my string and json_encode is a php function that encodes an object on the server side.

It seems that json encoder ignores ' chars and only converts " to \". So when one of my variables inside $this->params contains a ' character there is a Javascript error.

For example:

```
var params = dojo.fromJson('{"id":"11","object_type":"Let's go"}');
```

What is the best way to approach this ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: Before encoding, can you replace all `'` with `\'`?

Comment: @ianpgall — *after* encoding. This is trying to put a JSON text *in* a JavaScript string.

Comment: @Quentin Yep, crap, that's what I meant. Just kept confusing the order of things happening :)

Comment: @ianpgall Thats a good idea. I'm looking for the best and the simplest approach this problem.

Comment: Yeah the answer provided is probably the "best and simplest". For some reason, that hadn't come to mind first for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are producing the JSON yourself, you can trust it, so you don't need to treat it as JSON and can treat it as JS instead.

```
var params = <?=json_encode($this->params); ?>;
```

PHP's JSON encoder will escape `</script>` for you so you don't need to worry about terminating your script element with your data.

Comment: I made a few tests some time ago and it didn't. It probably depends on the version of json_encode function. The version in php 5.3.8 always encodes utf8 chars in a way that is not understood by javascript.

Comment: [works for me](http://dorward.me.uk/tmp/encode.php) on PHP 5.3.3 (with security patches)

Comment: Since JSON is a subset (except for one or two edge cases which I think revolve around control characters) of JavaScript, it is hard to imagine how PHP could output JSON that a JavaScript parser couldn't parse.

Comment: @Quentin: It seems that You're right about encoding utf8 and php. I wonder why I had such bad results some time ago. And your solution regarding ' solves my problem. Thanks for your help.